# Change this "2022-07-26T12:10:07.000+0000" format to DateTime with 12 hrs format? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, time

How i can extract the Time alone in this format "2022-07-26T12:10:07.000+0000" and show in 12hrs.

The output i am supposed to get is "5:40 PM", but i am getting 12.10 AM.

How to get exact time in the above mentioned format?

This is the method i followed to parse the DateTime.

```
 String getTimeStringNew(String date) {
 DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+SSSS");
 var dateValue = dateFormat.parse(date);
 DateFormat dateFormat1 = DateFormat("hh:mm a");
 var value = dateFormat1.format(dateValue);
 return value;}
```

In this method i am getting "12:10 AM".

But correct time is "5.40 PM".

What is the mistake i am doing here. Please correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2022-07-26T12:10:07.000+0000

Here 2022 is year

07 is month

26 is day

12 is hour

10 is minutes

07 is seconds.

So you will get 12.10 only

Maybe you are recieving the time in UTC.

You can use .toLocal to convert it to local time

```dart
var dateLocal = dateUtc.toLocal();
```

**Edit**

```
String getTimeStringNew(String date) {
 DateTime _localDate = DateTime.parse(date).toLocal();

 DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+SSSS");
 var dateValue = dateFormat.format(_localDate);
 DateFormat dateFormat1 = DateFormat("hh:mm a");
 var value = dateFormat1.format(_localDate);
 return value;}
```

Comment: But in Angular they using pipe to show the parsed time output. They getting 5.40 PM? Why not in Flutter? Please any idea

Comment: While parsing maybe a locale is also added in angular

Comment: How can i add the same locale in Flutter? Any option for that?

Comment: All you have to do it convert the string to a datetime value and .toLocal()

Comment: String getTimeStringNew(String date) {
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
  var dateValue = dateFormat.parse(date).toLocal();
  DateFormat dateFormat1 = DateFormat("hh:mm a");
  var value = dateFormat1.format(dateValue);
  return value;
} I added tolocal(). But same value i am getting?

Comment: I have used your edited method. But i am getting 

Trying to read T from 2022-07-16 12:03:45.000 at position 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246778/discussion-between-siva-and-kaushik-chandru).

Comment: Thanks chandru. 
This method works now.
String getTimeStringNew2(String date) {
  DateTime _localDate = DateTime.parse(date).toLocal();
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+SSSS");
  var dateValue = dateFormat.format(_localDate);
  DateFormat dateFormat1 = DateFormat("hh:mm a");
  var value = dateFormat1.format(_localDate);
  return value;
}
This gives correct Time. 
Thanks for your help.